# Merging [reviews] into [review]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

At the moment, we have [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) and [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reviews). The questions in both tags are about creating reviewing software.

The [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) tag has [256 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=votes) and a low quality tag wiki and excerpt.

The [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reviews) tag has [105 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reviews?sort=votes) and no tag wiki or a excerpt.

**Can the [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reviews) be merged into [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review)?**